# Join 2 tables on 2 different servers

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

The 2 servers are linked but I am getting an error when trying to run:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Invalid object name 'COI_port.Mess.agent_data'

SQL code:

```
SELECT 
    DATEPART(Hour, Chat) AS Interval, Chat,
    msg.RepRegion, msg.AgentRole,
    msg.Person, msg.Chat, msg.ChatStart, ChatEnd,
    --columns needed
    [AgentMessages], [ConsumerMessages],
    [ResolutionHrs], [FirstRespSecs], [Abandoned],
    --get interval online time    
    away.ntlogin, away.report_dt, away.int_interval,
    away.backsoonsecs, away.awaysecs, away.onlinesecs
FROM 
    [REGIONAL_OI].[east].[MsgDetails] (nolock) msg  
--join tables    
FULL OUTER JOIN
    [COI_port].[Mess].[agent_data](nolock) away ON msg.Interval = away.int 
                                                AND msg.Person = away.login  
WHERE 
    msg.Chat >= GETDATE() - 14
```

Comment: This isn't MySQL

Comment: Yeah, this is ms sql server.

Comment: `[COI_port].[Mess].agent_data` is a three part name - so the first part is interpreted as a database name. `getdate()-14` is a bad habit - stop developing it any further. Use dateadd. And make an effort to format your query so that it is readable - encourage others to help you by helping them read and understand your query with less effort.

Comment: Speaking of bad habits .......see [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere) - it is *not recommended* to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Comment: with my place of work, they make us use (nolock) @marc_s

Comment: I am very new to this, so I pretty much copy from other reports I see built. I am not very familiar with dateadd but i will read up on it @SMor

Answer (score 0):

In your query you used **[COI_port].[Mess].[agent_data]** to call a table from another server. But you need to use **dbo** between database name and table name as below:

**[COI_port].[Mess].dbo.agent_data**

So  the query will be:

```
SELECT 
    DATEPART(Hour, Chat) AS Interval, Chat,
    msg.RepRegion, msg.AgentRole,
    msg.Person, msg.Chat, msg.ChatStart, ChatEnd,
    --columns needed
    [AgentMessages], [ConsumerMessages],
    [ResolutionHrs], [FirstRespSecs], [Abandoned],
    --get interval online time    
    away.ntlogin, away.report_dt, away.int_interval,
    away.backsoonsecs, away.awaysecs, away.onlinesecs
FROM 
    [REGIONAL_OI].[east].[MsgDetails] (nolock) msg  
--join tables    
FULL OUTER JOIN
    [COI_port].[Mess].dbo.agent_data(nolock) away ON msg.Interval = away.int 
                                                AND msg.Person = away.login  
WHERE 
    msg.Chat >= GETDATE() - 14
```

Comment: If you could be more specific. Isnt it already a part of the query?